# How to write this Javascript code to show/hide for each personal elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

How can I write this code in a loop?
Actually I am using some different links to show and hide box for each related link. I want to show/hide box for each link showing information related to that link.

```
function hidedetailbox1()
{document.getElementById("plc1").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox1()
{document.getElementById("plc1").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox2()
{ document.getElementById("plc2").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox2()
{document.getElementById("plc2").style.display="block"; }

function hidedetailbox3()
{document.getElementById("plc3").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox3()
{document.getElementById("plc3").style.display="block"; }

function hidedetailbox4()
{document.getElementById("plc4").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox4()
{document.getElementById("plc4").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox5()
{document.getElementById("plc5").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox5()
{document.getElementById("plc5").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox6()
{document.getElementById("plc6").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox6()
{document.getElementById("plc6").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox7()
{document.getElementById("plc7").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox7()
{document.getElementById("plc7").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox8()
{document.getElementById("plc8").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox8()
{document.getElementById("plc8").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox9()
{document.getElementById("plc9").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox9()
{document.getElementById("plc9").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox10()
{document.getElementById("plc10").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox10()
{document.getElementById("plc10").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox11()
{document.getElementById("plc11").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox11()
{document.getElementById("plc11").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox12()
{document.getElementById("plc12").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox12()
{document.getElementById("plc12").style.display="block";}

function hidedetailbox13()
{document.getElementById("plc13").style.display="none";}
function showdetailbox13()
{document.getElementById("plc13").style.display="block";}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a function like this...

```
var toggleDisplay = function(i, hide) {
    document.getElementById('plc' + i).style.display = hide ? 'none' : '';
}
```

You pass it the number (as `i`) and whether it should hide or reset (as `hide`) the `display` property.

Comment: ok i think this answer is good but how to use it with html i am using     <li onmouseover="showdetailbox10()" onmouseout="hidedetailbox10()">

Comment: You should really read a [good JavaScript tutorial](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) if that is tripping you up.

Comment: @alex since your function is called "toggle" no need for the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @alfasin Why not? If you want it to be analogous with jQuery, sure, but that's not a requirement of calling a function `toggle`. Also, jQuery's `toggleClass()` does use the second argument as a *switch*.

Comment: @alex why not ? because the meaning of "toggle" is change of state, back and forth, between two states (like on/off). So if you want to implement it with the second parameter - I would change the name of the function to "changeState()" or something like that ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function hidedetailbox(id){
....
```

Comment: if you would put a little bit more effort and write the second line: "document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";}" you would get another +1

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned jquery. You can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('.boxlink').click(function(e) {
    $($(e.target).attr('href')).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Your links in HTML will look something like this:

```
<a href="#plc1" class="boxlink"> Toggle PLC 1</a>
<a href="#plc2" class="boxlink"> Toggle PLC 2</a>
```

Comment: What's with that selector? `this` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 10 comments listed in the page, 
when you display it from the server, in your server script keep a count like

```
<div id="1">comment1</div>
<div id="2">comment2</div>
<div id="3">comment3</div>
etc...
```

if it's any other content like a image, you can use

```
<...name="1"....>
```

now you can handle them in a loop like this,

```
for(i++){
 getElementById(i); //handle it the way you want here.
}
```

further if you have a specific name for the element, you can concat with the "i"
like 
    getElementById("comment"+i);

Suggestion: you can use jquery to do this for you 
[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) .hide() can be a good thing to look at..
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

toggle example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var toggleDisplay = function(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td onmouseover="toggleDisplay(1);">Test toggle</td><td id=1 name=1 >Toggle me!</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```